# Calendar objects gives two different date on Samsung note 2

Tags: android, datetime, calendar

I have the following code

```
{
Calendar mSunday = getToday();
    mSunday.add(Calendar.YEAR, 2);
    mSunday.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);

    Calendar mMonday = getToday();
    mMonday.add(Calendar.YEAR, 2);
    mMonday.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
    mMonday.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);

}
public static Calendar getToday() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, 0);
    return calendar;
}
```

I log the dates and my desired output should be

```
Sun Jun 03 00:00:00 IST 2018
Mon May 28 00:00:00 IST 2018
```

but when I run the same code in Samsung Note 2, I get the output as

```
Sun Jun 10 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2018
Mon May 28 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2018
```

Can someone please explain why the difference while using Samsung Note 2 since Calendar is a Java object and should be independent of android version model or whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on calender. You just need to Local in calender object.

Comment: Can you provide an example ?? and explanation of why the above code works uniformly on all devices but Note 2.

Comment: I manually checked if the difference between the dates is more than 6 days or not. If more I manually change it

Comment: Can you provide an example ?? and explanation of why the above code works uniformly on all devices but Note 2